# Inherited form's size change back to base form size

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created `frmGen` from inheriting a base `FixedDialog` as follows;

```
public partial class FixedDialog : Window
{
    public FixedDialog()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public partial class frmGen : FixedDialog
{ 
    public frmGen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And I call `frmGen` instance as follows;

```
frmGen gen = new frmGen();
gen.ShowDialog();
```

`FixedDialog`'s `Size` is `320,480` and `frmGen`'s `Size` is `800, 400`. When initializing the instance, `gen`'s `Size` is `800, 400`. But after or during `gen.ShowDialog()` it reverts back to `FixedDialog`'s `Size`. I want the `frmGen` to be the size it's defined, not inheriting from `FixedDialog`. This also caused the `frmGen` to improperly `CenterScreen`.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: `Window` is the top most parent of the structure.

```
public partial class Window : Form
{
    public Window()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Override the `DefaultSize` property and return the size that you want in each of the classes.

Comment: @CodyGray Same issue.

Comment: Then post more code. Something is overriding the size. There is no way that the code you've posted would repro this problem, nothing changes the size. What is `Window`? Are you setting a size there? Don't set sizes in constructors.

Comment: `Window` is the top most parent of the structure. In that nothing overrides the size. Actually after calling the `frmGen gen = new frmGen();` size is OK. But during the `gen.ShowDialog();` it reverts back.

Comment: What is the value of the `StartPosition` property?

Comment: @IvanStoev `CenterScreen`

Comment: Hmm, tried with a clean WinForms project (VS2015, NET4.5.2  if that matters), doesn't happen.